# What will be the redirectUrl after authentication for MSAdal in ionic 4?

Tags: angular, azure, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, adal

When the user is authenticated successfully I want to redirect it to the app root page. What will be the redirectUrl for authContext.acquireTokenAsync?

```
      let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');
  authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net', this.clientId, 'http://localhost:8100/')
    .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
      alert('Token is' + authResponse.accessToken);
      alert('Token will expire on' + authResponse.expiresOn);
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
    })
    .catch((e: any) => {
      alert('Authentication failed'+ e);
      this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
    });
```

Comment: I am looking for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the app was registered as WebApp on azure active directory. I have registered a new app as Native app on active directory. with redirect url "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" and it works perfectly now. Here is my code

```
    let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/common');
authContext.acquireTokenAsync('https://graph.windows.net','<Your Native App client ID>' , 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob', '', null)
  .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
    this.presentToast('Token is' + authResponse.accessToken + ' and expires on ' + authResponse.expiresOn);
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
  })
  .catch((e: any) => {
    this.presentToast('Authentication failed ' + e)
  })
```